# Eclipse CDT link static lib according to active configuration in lib project

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

For a C application 'A' that uses lib 'B' built from a C static lib project I want to include to lib that is generated according to the B active configuration (Debug /Release/other).

Right now I include /b/Debug/ in the library paths but I wanted something like /b/{activeConfigFor:b}/ in order to change the lib that I include according to the test that I want to do.

Comment: Set up 2 different _Build Configurations_

Comment: That's the only solution? I wanted my Debug to use the active configuration lib (Debug or release) and that Release to use just Release

Comment: I meant: you should define different Build Configuration for each combination you need. AFAIK there isn't an option to link a project to active status of another project into eclipse. Otherwise you can build a new project that integrate lib and app, but is a bad workaround, my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The solution it's to add library path /b/${config_name:b}. If you added it on Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Library Paths don't forget to check "Is a workspace path".

This works but somehow everytime I change the build configuration in 'b' eclipse reorganizes the lib loading order, which in this case breaks my build. I'm using System WOrkbench for STM32 1.9, which is based on Eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2).